# How long does it exactly take for a view to rotate in iOS?

Tags: ios, orientation, rotation, nstimer

I want to use NSTimer to call a method once the view is done rotating. How long does the view take to rotate exactly? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have to use a timer.

in apple's documentation there's an even trigger which is fired after the iphone rotates

see here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:

I believe you can just implement this method:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` and put your code in there.